# Dockerized wordpress front-end/admin does not load completely (fails to load stylesheet and JS files)

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've deployed a simple WordPress site using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose) method. From the server, everything looks good, all containers and services are up and running, the admin panel and website is accessible. No SSL issues, and `certbot` inspection exits with `code 0`.

Though, it appears that some `.css` and `.js` files are not loading, making the website partially loaded and plugins and themes not working properly.
Here is the `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
  image: mysql:8.0
  container_name: db
  restart: unless-stopped
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./backup:/home/backup
  command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
  networks:
    - app-network


wordpress:
  depends_on:
    - db
  image: wordpress:5.5.1-php7.4-fpm-alpine
  container_name: wordpress
  restart: unless-stopped
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
    - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
  volumes:
    - wordpress:/var/www/html
    - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
    - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
    - ./backup:/home/backup
  networks:
    - app-network


webserver:
  depends_on:
    - wordpress
  image: nginx:1.18.0-alpine
  container_name: webserver
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - wordpress:/var/www/html
    - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
  networks:
    - app-network

certbot:
  depends_on:
    - webserver
  image: certbot/certbot
  container_name: certbot
  volumes:
    - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    - wordpress:/var/www/html
    

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and `nginx.conf` :

```
server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;

      server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

      location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
              allow all;
              root /var/www/html;
      }

      location / {
              rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
      }
}

server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

      index index.php index.html index.htm;

      root /var/www/html;

      server_tokens off;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

#gzip on
      gzip on;
      gzip_vary on;
      gzip_min_length 1000;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
      gzip_disable "msie6";
      gzip_comp_level 6;
      gzip_types              *;
      client_max_body_size 256M;


      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
      add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
      add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
      # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
      # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

      location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
              include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
              try_files $uri =404;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
              fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
              deny all;
      }

      location = /favicon.ico {
              log_not_found off; access_log off;
      }
      location = /robots.txt {
              log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
      }
      location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
              expires max;
              log_not_found off;
      }
      
      location ~ \.css {
          add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
      }
      location ~ \.js {
          add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
      }        
      
}
```

Even debug mode didn't show any error whatsoever. From inspecting console, it shows the followings:

> Refused to apply style from 'https://DOMAIN/wp-content/plugins/updraftplus/css/tether-shepherd/shepherd-theme-arrows-plain-buttons.min.css?ver=1.16.56' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
>
> GET https://DOMAIN/wp-content/plugins/updraftplus/includes/tether-shepherd/shepherd.min.js?ver=1.16.56 net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post you compose yaml and nginx configuration.

Comment: I've added docker-compose.yaml and nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

Although I redeployed the whole project from scratch, I suppose the problem was due to mounting the themes, plugins and backup folders in `docker-compose.yml`, without the right permission. Because I've omitted these mounts in the new deployment, and all went well.